# Problem Understanding Access Modifiers in VB.Net with List( Of Object)

Tags: vb.net, shared, access-modifiers, generic-list

I've recently been updating a lot of my code to comply with proper n-tier architecture and OO programming, following examples from a book.

I'm starting to get problems now because I don't fully understand the access modifiers.

If I run the following code I get an error at the line

```
Dim clientFamilyDataAccessLayer As New ClientFamilyDAO
```

in the BLL at the point it creates an instance of the DAL. The full error message is: "The type initializer for 'ClientFamilyDAO' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How do I use these function to create a list of ClientFamily objects that I can then work with?

On my UI layer I'm creating a list of objects; ClientFamilies

```
Dim listOfClientFamilies As List(Of ClientFamily) = ClientFamily.GetClientFamiliesByKRM(selectedEmployee.StaffNumber)
```

This is the function in the BLL

```
Public Shared Function GetClientFamiliesByKRM(ByVal krmStaffNumber As Integer) As List(Of ClientFamily)

        Dim clientFamilyDataAccessLayer As New ClientFamilyDAO
        Return clientFamilyDataAccessLayer.GetClientFamiliesByKRM(krmStaffNumber)

    End Function
```

and this is function in the DAL

```
Public Function GetClientFamiliesByKRM(ByVal staffNumber As Integer) As List(Of ClientFamily)

        Dim currentConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(_connectionString)

        Dim currentCommand As New SqlCommand
        currentCommand.CommandText = mainSelectStatement & " WHERE Key_Relationship_Manager = @StaffNumber ORDER BY Client_Family_Name"
        currentCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffNumber", staffNumber)
        currentCommand.Connection = currentConnection

        Dim listOfClientFamilies As New List(Of ClientFamily)

        Using currentConnection

            currentConnection.Open()

            Dim currentDataReader As SqlDataReader = currentCommand.ExecuteReader()

            Do While currentDataReader.Read

                Dim newClientFamily As AECOM.ClientFamily = PopulateClientFamily(currentDataReader)

                listOfClientFamilies.Add(newClientFamily)

            Loop

        End Using

        Return listOfClientFamilies

    End Function
```

Here's the full ClientFamilyDAO Class:

```
    Public Class ClientFamilyDAO

    Private Const mainSelectStatement As String = "SELECT Client_Family_ID, Client_Family_Name, Key_Relationship_Organisation, Key_Relationship_Manager, Obsolete, Market_Sector_ID FROM Client_Families"

    Private Shared ReadOnly _connectionString As String = String.Empty

    Shared Sub New()

        _connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ClientFamilyManagementConnectionString").ConnectionString

    End Sub

    Public Function GetClientFamiliesByKRM(ByVal staffNumber As Integer) As List(Of ClientFamily)

        Dim currentConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(_connectionString)

        Dim currentCommand As New SqlCommand
        currentCommand.CommandText = mainSelectStatement & " WHERE Key_Relationship_Manager = @StaffNumber ORDER BY Client_Family_Name"
        currentCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffNumber", staffNumber)
        currentCommand.Connection = currentConnection

        Dim listOfClientFamilies As New List(Of ClientFamily)

        Using currentConnection

            currentConnection.Open()

            Dim currentDataReader As SqlDataReader = currentCommand.ExecuteReader()

            Do While currentDataReader.Read

                Dim newClientFamily As AECOM.ClientFamily = PopulateClientFamily(currentDataReader)

                listOfClientFamilies.Add(newClientFamily)

            Loop

        End Using

        Return listOfClientFamilies

    End Function

    Private Function PopulateClientFamily(ByVal currentDataReader As SqlDataReader) As AECOM.ClientFamily

        Dim newClientFamily As New AECOM.ClientFamily

        If Not (currentDataReader.IsDBNull(currentDataReader.GetOrdinal("Client_Family_ID"))) Then
            newClientFamily.ClientFamilyID = currentDataReader("Client_Family_ID")
        End If

        If Not (currentDataReader.IsDBNull(currentDataReader.GetOrdinal("Client_Family_Name"))) Then
            newClientFamily.ClientFamilyName = currentDataReader("Client_Family_Name")
        End If

        If Not (currentDataReader.IsDBNull(currentDataReader.GetOrdinal("Key_Relationship_Organisation"))) Then
            Select Case currentDataReader("Key_Relationship_Organisation")
                Case False
                    newClientFamily.IsKeyRelationshipOrganisation = False
                Case True
                    newClientFamily.IsKeyRelationshipOrganisation = True
            End Select
        End If

        If Not (currentDataReader.IsDBNull(currentDataReader.GetOrdinal("Key_Relationship_Manager"))) Then
            newClientFamily.KeyRelationshipManagerStaffNumber = currentDataReader("Key_Relationship_Manager")
        End If

        If Not (currentDataReader.IsDBNull(currentDataReader.GetOrdinal("Obsolete"))) Then
            Select Case currentDataReader("Obsolete")
                Case False
                    newClientFamily.Obsolete = False
                Case True
                    newClientFamily.Obsolete = True
            End Select
        End If

        If Not (currentDataReader.IsDBNull(currentDataReader.GetOrdinal("Market_Sector_ID"))) Then
            newClientFamily.MarketSectorID = currentDataReader("Market_Sector_ID")
        End If

        Return newClientFamily

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: In the BLL: Dim clientFamilyDataAccessLayer As New ClientFamilyDAO

Comment: PopulateClientFamily is likely returning nothing or has the error.  I would start there with a breakpoint and step into it.

Comment: Added the full error message to the question above

Comment: What is the code for initializing ClientFamilyDAO?

Comment: As Judah requested, can you show the code for the ClientFamilyDAO class?  At least show the code for the constructor.

Comment: I've added the full ClientFamilyDAO class at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue doesn't relate to access modifiers, rather it is more to do with the exception message you get. The following line within the constructor of `ClientFamilyDAO` would seem to be causing the issue:

```
_connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ClientFamilyManagementConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

Are you sure `ClientFamilyManagementConnectionString` exists in the configuration?

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid. Thanks Mr. Dissapointment that's sorted it. I guess I need to work out how to get more info from the error message.

Comment: No problem, sometimes we just need a second set of eyes - glad you're sorted.